# javafx-maven-plugin mac pkg installer does not show app icon

Tags: java, macos, maven, javafx, installation

I use the following maven plugin configuration on my mac to generate the native installers.

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>com.zenjava</groupId>
    <artifactId>javafx-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>8.5.0</version>
    <configuration>
        <appName>${project.name}</appName>
        <title>${project.name}</title>
        <description>${project.description}</description>
        <vendor>example</vendor>
        <certCountry>com</certCountry>
        <mainClass>${mainClass}</mainClass>
        <needMenu>true</needMenu>
        <additionalAppResources>src/main/deploy/package/all</additionalAppResources>
        <bundleArguments>
            <icon.ico>src/main/resources/icons/Icon.ico</icon.ico>
            <icon.png>src/main/resources/icons/Icon_32.png</icon.png>
            <icon.icns>src/main/resources/icons/Icon.icns</icon.icns>
        </bundleArguments>
        <jfxMainAppJarName>${project.build.finalName}.jar</jfxMainAppJarName>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

The Example.app folder and the Example.dmg installer both show the correct app icon, but the Example.pkg installer shows the plain java jar image (1).
How can change that image (1)?

Is it possible to change the small icon in the title bar (2) as well?

[image: JavaFX PKG Installer OSX]

The folder structure of my project:

- src

  - main

    - java

      - *.java
    - resources

      - icons

        - Icon.ico
        - Icon.icns
        - Icon_*.png
    - deploy

      - package

        - all

          - LICENSE
- pom.xml

I tried with Oracle Java JDK 8 Update 40 and Update 101 (64bit)

See also: [javafx-maven-plugin#224](https://github.com/javafx-maven-plugin/javafx-maven-plugin/issues/224)

Comment: Before asking this on StackOverflow, please try to reach out on the project itself on github. (Disclaimer: I'm the maintainer of the javafx-maven-plugin)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To make it dedundant, I'm pasting the answer here too:

Hi there,

this is no bug, it is "just" undocumented (seems there are a lot of people who know this, or very few people who use this feature).

Please see the `getConfig_BackgroundImage`-method:

https://github.com/teamfx/openjfx-8u-dev-rt/blob/fd634925571310284b02d89ff512552e795ba5e8/modules/fxpackager/src/main/java/com/oracle/tools/packager/mac/MacPkgBundler.java#L192

```
private File getConfig_BackgroundImage(Map<String, ? super Object> params) {
    return new File(CONFIG_ROOT.fetchFrom(params), APP_NAME.fetchFrom(params) + "-background.png");
}
```

Please create some image and place it below `src/main/deploy/package/macosx`, it has to be PNG-fileformat. This file should be named `${project.name}-background.png` to get fetched by the bundler.

This should have been printed out to you while having `<verbose>` set to `true`.

General advice: turn VERBOSE-switch on ;) the packager itself behaves different (like not removing the temporary created working-folder, making it possible to further adjust your stuff) and prints out more important debugging-stuff.

The verbose-hint is even mentioned in the official documentation:
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/deploy/self-contained-packaging.html#BCGHHDGC

Answer (score 1):

Late reply, but if you still wonder how to change the small icon in the title bar (2) you can do that simply by `right-clicking` the `pkg-file` and choose `Get Info` in the menu, then you simply `drag-and-drop` your `.icns-file` on top of the current one next to the pkg name. This will change the pkg-icon and what is shown in the title bar during installation. This does not appear to break the product signature either which is good, see picture below...

[image]

To verify signature still holds after icon change:

`spctl -a -v --type install MyAppName-1.0.pkg`
`MyAppName-1.0.pkg: accepted`
`source=Developer ID`